# How can I get rid of this deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have 2 queries that get involved in a deadlock situaution displayed in the Deadlockgraph below. (Seitensperre means pagelock)

The query in process 55 is the deadlock victim. It is a select  that includes the tables order and payment.

The query on process 95 has a couple of queries in it
At the beginning ist does a couple of selects to store some values into variables (table order is accessed)
It then updates table order and after that table payment.

I dont understand how a deadlock can arise from this situation. Can you explain what the deadlock caused and what I can do about this? I guess I just have  hard time reading the deadlock-graph.

Here are the resources involved.

```
<resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1104059019" subresource="FULL" dbid="9" objectname="mycompany.dbo.order" id="lock1b9596980" mode="S" associatedObjectId="1104059019">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process443bac8" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process20fc5eda8" mode="IX" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1825971" dbid="9" objectname="mycompany.dbo.Payment" id="lock1bca33000" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594063159296">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process20fc5eda8" mode="IX"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process443bac8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
```

[image]

EDIT

Here is the Update query (process 95)

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateOrderDetails]
(
    @id_order               int,
    @customerComment        NText,
    @salutationBilling      nvarchar(50) = '00',
    @companyNameBilling     nvarchar(100)= ''

        ...some more Parameters
)
AS
DECLARE @user_change int, @id_orderAddress int,
        @id_voucherType int, @id_orderPayment int, @id_paymentMode int


SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SELECT @user_change = 0
SELECT @id_orderAddress = 0
SELECT @id_voucherType = 0
SELECT @id_orderPayment = 0
SELECT @id_paymentMode = 0


SELECT @user_change = id FROM user
 WHERE logonName = @user_str

SELECT @id_orderAddress = id_orderAddress FROM order
 WHERE [id] = @id_order

SELECT @id_voucherType = [id] FROM voucherType
 WHERE [name] = @voucherTypeName


SELECT @id_orderPayment = [id_orderPayment] FROM order 
 WHERE [id] = @id_order 

SELECT @id_paymentMode = [id] FROM paymentMode
 WHERE [name] = @paymentModeName


IF @user_change = 0 GOTO ERR
IF @id_voucherType = 0 GOTO ERR

UPDATE order
SET
[id_voucherType]        =       @id_voucherType,
[customerComment]       =       @customerComment,
[causeOfCancellation]   =       @causeOfCancellation
...some more fields to update

WHERE
[id] = @id_order

IF @id_orderAddress = 0 GOTO ERR

UPDATE Address
SET
[salutationBilling]     =    @salutationBilling,
[companyNameBilling]    =    @companyNameBilling,
[firstNameBilling]      =    @firstNameBilling
...some more fields to update
WHERE
[id] = @id_orderAddress

IF @id_orderPayment = 0 OR @id_paymentMode = 0 GOTO ERR
UPDATE Payment
SET
[id_paymentMode]        =   @id_paymentMode,
[customerBankDepositor] =   @customerBankDepositor,
[customerBank]          =   @customerBank,
[customerBankCode]      =   @customerBankCode,
...some more fields to update
WHERE
[id] = @id_orderPayment

IF @@Error > 0 Goto ERR


RETURN 0

ERR:

return  -1;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Here is the select query (process 55)

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[searchOrders]
(
  @SelectType           INT
 ,@searchB2B            INT
 ,@VoucherNumber        NVARCHAR(50)  = null
 ,@FirstNameBilling     NVARCHAR(100) = null
    ... some more parameters
)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF  @SelectType = 0 and LEN(@VoucherNumber) > 0
 BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT  (o.id)
                    ,o.voucherNumber
                    ...some more columns

    FROM             order AS o
    LEFT JOIN        orderAssignment AS oa  ON o.id = oa.id_order
    LEFT JOIN        voucherType AS vt      ON o.id_voucherType = vt.id
    LEFT JOIN        Payment AS op      ON o.id_orderPayment = op.id
    LEFT JOIN        paymentMode AS pm      ON op.id_paymentMode = pm.id
    LEFT JOIN        orderAddress AS addr   ON o.id_orderAddress = addr.id
    LEFT JOIN        user AS u1             ON o.user_change = u1.id
    LEFT JOIN        user as u2             ON oa.id_user = u2.id   
    LEFT JOIN        b2bAccount as b2b      ON o.id_b2bAccount = b2b.id


    WHERE            o.voucherNumber like @VoucherNumber
    AND              o.isB2B = @searchB2B
 END
...some more cases depending on @SelectType but the actual query is with @SelectType = 0

RETURN

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Comment: How are you calling this proc?  I don't see any "BEGIN TRAN" statements, so I am wondering if you are doing this within a SqlTransaction context or not.

Comment: Yes the updateOrderDetails is called within a Transaction Context that is opened via ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it turned out that it was an issue with the calling code. Its difficult to explain, but basically a transaction was opened and handed over to a couple of methods.

I removed the transaction and the deadlocks went away.

Of course I have to re-implement the transaction again, and see if it is really a problem with how the transaction handling was implemented or if the transaction just spans for too long.

Comment: Well... have fun then. I think, I know the code... :)

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful if you could post the statements involved in each process, but here goes...

If the `SELECT` statements are doing aggregations they can acquire table locks. You could try using the `WITH(NOLOCK)` hint, if your use case allows for it.

The `UPDATE` statements really depend on the scope of records being modified - the selectivity of the `WHERE` condition and whether its making efficient use of indexes or not.

If the tables involved have any triggers you'll need to careful examine that code as well. In my experience they are the most common cause of deadlock situations. Especially when the statements being issued appear to be relatively simple at the surface. If you do find triggers, try disabling them and running the two statements in a test environment to verify whether they are causing your deadlock.

In the end, though, deadlocks can't always be prevented. You're best off optimizing what you can but always handling the case where one or both statements are selected as the victim and gracefully cleaning up / existing, or retrying the batch.

Answer (score 0):

Inside transaction, change queries like

```
SELECT @id_orderAddress = id_orderAddress FROM order
 WHERE [id] = @id_order
```

to following:

```
SELECT @id_orderAddress = id_orderAddress FROM order WITH(UPDLOCK)
 WHERE [id] = @id_order
```

This ensures that subsequent updates of same 'order' row do not cause deadlocks - 'order' rows are locked already at start of transaction.